# Determine position of arguments in drools

Tags: java, drools

I am executing drools rules with such parameters.

```
session.execute(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{fileName,tableName}));
```

where **fileName** and **tableName** = **String**

But when I run some rule:

```
rule"A"
when
 $fileName: String()
 $tableName: String()
then
 System.out.println($fileName + " " + $tableName);
end
```

I have **fileName** in **BOTH** arguments.

```
fileName = fileName
tableName = fileName
```

How can I declare them, to have correct argument values in the rule ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the execute call you have two facts in your Working Memory:

```
String "filename"
String "tablename"
```

The rule will match a pattern "String()" with any of these two strings:

```
$fileName: String() ... matches String "filename" and String "tablename"
$tableName: String() ... matches String "filename" and String "tablename"
```

So the rule will fire four times, giving you all combinations. - It is usually bad practice to insert run-of-the-mill data types such as String or Map or List. They aren't easily identified. Declare (String is final) classes Filename and Tablename as { String value; ... }, insert objects of these classes and write the rule as

```
Filename( $fn: value )
Tablename( $tn: value )
```

Answer (score 0):

Also another way (recived this proposal in comments).
We can use **globals**.

1. Set globals in your session

   session.setGlobal("fileName",fileName)

   session.setGlobal("tableName", tableName)
2. Don't forget to set in .drl file

   global java.lang.String fileName

   global java.lang.String tableName

   - But in **ADDITION** (never never never use this aproach with cuncurrency app.)